# VBA Userforms (Excel) are same font and size but display at different sizes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having an issue with my userforms when they display. They will sometimes come up larger than what they should be. I have changed my option settings already so that it optimizes for compatibility. This didn't change anything. I have 2 different workbooks that have different useforms. One displays correctly and the other workbook is oversized. (I attached a screenshot of both userforms side by side.

I don't understand what else I could do or why it is like this. I have been googling for a few days and there isn't much that I could find other than changing the display settings, which didn't help me.

[Here is the screenshot of the 2 side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsJZe.png)

Comment: Look at the Zoom property of each form. Are they the same?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kz5C.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kz5C.png)

Comment: Yeah, they are both at 100. I played with this a little bit as well. That option seemed to change the font size but not the overall size of the userform. My issue seems to have both of them grow. One day it fit on the screen just fine and now the bottom of the userform is sitting off the bottom of my screen

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not have any other idea. I had a similar problem several years ago. I didn't solve it, but I used a workaround: during runtime, the windows were different from the design stage. The fault was that on some computers I had a different screen zooms. The solution was to code the dimensions and fonts at initialization. That helped my situation. I do not know if this helps you, but it helped me. If you send me the Excel file, I will take a look.

Comment: I will look into trying this as an option. I appreciate you taking the time to pop in and help! Thank you!